# How to write and read Data in form of UImage in Realm database swift

Tags: swift, realm

I have a requirement for an editor app where i want to store data in the form of image ,audio and video in realm Object as i am new to realm and  swift.where i am able to write data but how to read in form of array of objects.

Answer (score 1):

General best practice for Realm is to try and avoid saving large binary blobs to Realm; especially if they can simply be saved on the hard drive next to the Realm file. If you need a Realm `Object` to represent the file, you can store the file path to the file in Realm as a `String` property.

If you still have a specific need to write a `UIImage` to a Realm object, it's necessary to convert it to NSData first so it can be saved to disk. This usually means converting it to a JPEG or PNG.

```
// Write a UIImage as a PNG to Realm
let myImage: UIImage = ...
let myImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImage) as NSData?

if let myImageData = myImageData {
   // A Realm `Object` with an `NSData` 
   let myObject = MyObject() property

   myObject.imageData = myImageData

   let realm = try! Realm()
   try! realm.write {
      realm.add(myObject)
   }
}

// Get a UIImage from Realm
let realm = try! Realm()
let myObject = realm.objects(MyObject.self).first!
let myImage = UIImage(data: myObject.imageData)
```